# How to login with Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to loop through a list I've pulled from an excel sheet. I'm saving that data for later. But I think I need to use a for loop to run through that list and go to this website each time, using the siteCode variable to input later to put in data. However, I'm stuck at the login page. Each time I login, I get an error saying the program can't find the selector. Any help would be great.

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# Get Excel Worksheet
df = pd.read_excel('G:\Automation\ATM Status.xlsx')

# Create array of site codes
siteCodeArray = df["Terminal ID"].to_numpy()

# Loop through array
for siteCode in siteCodeArray:
    # Go to MyNCR
    DRIVER_PATH = 'G:/Automation/chromedriver'  # import Chrome driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)

    #myNcr = driver.get('https://myncr.ncr.com/f5-w-68747470733a2f2f706f7274616c2e6e63722e636f6d$$/myncr/')
    # Error handling for 404 or redirects needs to be added here

    def myNcrLogin():
        driver.get("https://myncr.ncr.com/f5-w68747470733a2f2f706f7274616c2e6e63722e636f6d$$/myncr/")
        driver.find_element_by_name("callback_0").send_keys("blah")
        driver.find_element_by_name("callback_1").send_keys("blah")
        driver.find_element_by_name("callback_2").click()
    # Login to MyNCR
```

Comment: "I get an error saying the program can't find the selector." -- perhaps the person who voted to close your question wanted you to post the full error traceback as part of your question. Paraphrasing the error rarely helps us all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait for the elements to render.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select, WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://myncr.ncr.com/f5-w68747470733a2f2f706f7274616c2e6e63722e636f6d$$/myncr/")

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "callback_0"))
    ).send_keys("Hello")
    
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "callback_1"))
    ).send_keys("World")
```

Comment: Usually, when you get the answer that works for you, you [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer.

Comment: Sorry about that. Still fairly new to StackOverflow. I've accepted it, thanks again :)